# Oracle Forms - Enable / disable tabular list item rows based on the query data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a text item ('TXT_EG_PER') and a list item('LI_P') as tabular in a datablock('DB') as shown in the picture.
[image: picture]
 I want to make list items enable/disable singly based on the row data.

I used 'TXT_EG_PER's WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger. My code in it:

```
IF smt..    THEN
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY  ('DB.LI_P',
                     ENABLED,
                     property_true);
ELSE
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY  ('DB.LI_P',
                     ENABLED,
                     property_false);
END IF;
```

But it makes all list items enable or disable. I want to do it row based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` instead. Its usage is described in Forms Online Help System. Have a look, as it doesn't have the same parameters as `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` built-in, e.g.

```
set_item_instance_property(item, record, property value);
```

In your case, that *might* be

```
SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY  ('DB.LI_P',
                             :system.trigger_record,
                             ENABLED,
                             property_true);
```

Comment: I got "too many declarations of 'SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY' match this call" error.

Comment: Which means that you probably misused it. Check the documentation.

Comment: I assigned :system.trigger_record to a variable and used this variable. This error is gone. Then I checked documentation. My possible related properties (10g): "INSERT_ALLOWED, NAVIGABLE, VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE". I tried all of them but didn't work. Which one should i use? I used this in LI_P's "WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE" trigger, is it wrong? And what should be my propety value? I'm new on Oracle Form

Comment: NAVIGABLE is probably the closest to what you need, i.e. that - if certain condition is met - user can't navigate to that item (and thus can't modify it). I don't know why it doesn't work; it *should*.

Comment: I recognized I couldn't explain it well. Records were full actually. TXT_EG_PER text fields were full. List item('LI_P')s were blank. So I used UPDATE_ALLOWED in related data block's "POST-QUERY" trigger and it worked.  This is final situation:     SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY ('DB.LI_P',
                                  current_record,
                                  UPDATE_ALLOWED,
                                  PROPERTY_TRUE);

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know.